# Access output of CommandLine Command in python

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess

I have a command for the commandline which is sent using python.

```
import subprocess
cmdline = 'tool.exe /j231_' #TOOL COMMAND
dir = r'D:\RC\tool.exe'
rc = subprocess.run("start cmd /K " + cmdline, cwd=dir, shell=True)
```

The output on the command line is:

```
Application directory is: D:\RC\tool.exe
Project 231_ loaded succesfully.
=========================================

Operation has terminated successfully.
```

I need to get the line *Project 231_ loaded succesfully.*, as a string in python. How can I do this? I tried using stdout, stderr but I could not do it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess
help(subprocess.run)
```

> Help on function run in module subprocess:
>
> ```
> run(*popenargs, input=None, capture_output=False, timeout=None, check=False, **kwargs)
> ```
>
> Run command with arguments and return a `CompletedProcess` instance.
>
> The returned instance will have attributes `args`, `returncode`,
> `stdout` and `stderr`. **By default, `stdout` and `stderr` are not
> captured**, and those attributes will be `None`. Pass `stdout=PIPE`
> and/or `stderr=PIPE` in order to capture them.
>
> …
> By default, all communication is in bytes, and therefore any "input"
> should be bytes, and the `stdout` and `stderr` will be bytes. If in
> text mode, any "input" should be a string, and `stdout` and `stderr`
> will be strings decoded according to locale encoding, or by "encoding"
> if set. Text mode is triggered by setting any of `text`, `encoding`,
> `errors` or `universal_newlines`.
>
> The other arguments are the same as for the `Popen` constructor.

Getting the above together [maybe adding some details from `help(subprocess.Popen)`], the following code snippet should run, and you can extract desired info from the `rc.stdout` string easy:

```
import subprocess
cmdline = 'tool.exe /j231_' #TOOL COMMAND
dir = r'D:\RC' # \tool.exe' # should be a directory
rc = subprocess.run(["cmd.exe", "/C", cmdline], cwd=dir, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, text=True)
print(rc.stdout)
```

---

Note the `/C` (instead of <strike>`/K`</strike>) switch for `cmd.exe`:

- `/C` Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
- `/K` Carries out the command specified by string but remains